# Why does eclipse say Local variable is not used even though it is used?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the following code

```
private List<String> getItems() {
    XmlDoc document = new XmlDoc();
    List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String itemNum;
    try {
        XmlUtils root = document.parse(xmlFile);
        List<XmlUtils> listNode = root.getChildNodes();
        for (XmlUtils node : listNode)  {
            itemNum = node.getValue();
        }
    } catch (XmlException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return itemList;
}
```

Even though I used the String itemNum inside the for loop eclipse says "The value of the local variable itemNum is not used". Why is that so?

Comment: Where do you use it? What effects do you think assignment has?

Comment: I see it at String itemNum;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because you're assigning a value to `itemNum`, but never *reading* it. It's a clear sign that the variable is unused. In fact, you can safely delete this line:

```
itemNum = node.getValue();
```

…And nothing will happen. Maybe you should actually *do* something with `itemNum` after assigning it.

Comment: is assigning a value to a variable not "using" it?

Comment: @user1629109 nope, you just put a value in there, but you're expected to do something with that value at a later point, if not, what's the use for it?

Comment: I added that Sting to the List and the warning message vanished. I was just curious though. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user1629109 perfect! it was my pleasure :)